# Clearing Obout Editor content

Tags: obout

Does anyone know how to clear the content of Oboout HTML Editor client side?
Their online documention says to use oboutGetEditor('editor').setContent(...). When I try oboutGetEditor('editor').setContent(""), I get script error ("Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method) at:

```
switch(a._mode){case"html":if(a._iframe&&a._iframe.contentWindow&&a._iframe.contentWindow.focus&&(a.isActivated||a._autoFocus)){if(!a._autoFocus&&!a._wasFocused)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see on this page:
http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/docs/client/Editor.aspx

```
var editorObject = $find("<%= myEditor.ClientID %>");
editorObject .set_content("Some new content...");
```